# defining a constructor class and initialising values

Tags: java, constructor

I'm stuck on a homework question which asks me to define a constructor for class Jar which initialises the variable position to 0 and the variable stone to null. Was just wondering if the code I did below is the right way to do this? Also am I able to initialise the values used in this constructor in a different class?

```java
public class Jar
{
    public int position;
    public Jar stone;

    public Jar()
    {
        position = 0;
        stone = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fine, but pay attention to `stone = null;` because you would flood your JVM with instances if you wrote `stone = new Jar();`!

Comment: remove the constructor alltogether. Unless you specify another constructor, the JVM will add a constructor that does exactly that when you compile the class.

Comment: *"Also am I able to initialise the values used in this constructor in a different class?"* Two things: 1. What do you mean by that? :-) I'm afraid it's not clear. 2. Ask **one** question per question, not two. :-)

Comment: @Stultuske you're totally right, but the task seems to be *to define a constructor…*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was just wondering if the code I did below is the right way to do this?

Yes, although:

1. As [Stultuske points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321794/defining-a-constructor-class-and-initialising-values/58321859#comment103002423_58321794), those are the default values that the fields will get even if you don't assign anything to them, so the constructor isn't necessary. But if the assignment said to write one...
2. I always advise being explicit:

   ```
   this.position = 0;
   this.stone = null;
   ```

   Java allows you to leave off the `this.` part, but I wouldn't.

Comment: what does the  this.  part do?

Comment: @Sepp1 it makes it an explicit point to the instance variable. in this case, it doesn't change much, but if you create another constructor with parameter names that are the same as the names of the instance variables, you would just change the value of the local variables if you didn't use this.

Comment: @Sepp1 - `this` within an instance method is a reference to the object that method is attached to. To access the instance fields and instance methods of that object, you use `this.name`. But (unfortunately) Java lets you leave the `this.` part off, it's optional. This should have been covered by your instructor/course by now, given the assignment you've described.